# Identifying Mapped drive from local drive

Tags: java, java-io

I am listing all available drives in my desktop using File.listRoots() in Java. I have some Mapped drives. When I list the roots it is fetching me local drives as well as mapped drives. In order to exclude the mapped drives I used following  code snippet:

```
for (File drive :File.listRoots()){
   String typeDescription = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemTypeDescription(drive);
}
```

Based on the type description returned I am filtering the drive. But this is not universally standard and not acceptable by other operating system. Only supported for windows. Also there is a language restriction (English only supported for type description). Can any one give me any other solution to filter the mapped drives globally.

Note:
It must be specific to JDK1.6

Comment: Any other solution will be platform specific. But since _All available drives_ is a solely a Windows term you're probably looking for windows only solution?

Comment: @Oleg Mikheev. Yeah.. I am looking only  for solution in windows.But in linux machine File.listRoots() returns only Root dir.  So no problem in Linux. I need to distinguish between mapped drive and local drive in windows platform...

Comment: Deleted my answer. I just tried it on OS X and I see the problem you're having. I will post another answer if I think of anything.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is only in Windows, why not use:

`if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows"))` ?

You could write a C++ program to do it (human) language independently using `IVdsDisk::GetProperties`, and then import it as a `native` function in Java (and tell the VM only to try to run the `native` method if you're running Windows.

[MSDN link to get you started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Check to see if `VDS_DISK_PROP.dwMediaType` is a `FILE_DEVICE_NETWORK` or a `FILE_DEVICE_NETWORK_FILE_SYSTEM`. You can see all the supported types here: [winioctrl.h](http://www.cs.uofs.edu/~beidler/Ada/win32/win32-winioctl.ads)

It's possible that value is accessible in Java, but Java generally doesn't have platform specific stuff so I doubt it.

Comment: @durron597.. I can differentiate OS using code snippet which you have mentioned above.. But think this scenario, when I have Installed windows OS in different language other than english I can not use the "Type description" to differentiate the mapped drives and local drives. If I want to differentiate them through the "type description" I have to check for OS language before I identifying map drive from local drive. It may lead to number of conditional checking as many languages as found in windows Os.

Comment: @vigneshkumarrathakumar: I updated the post, that may help you!